# global HandleErrorAttribute and custom Action HandleErrorAttribute be invoked many times in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filter

I Register a GlobalFilters for HandleErrorAttribute:

```
 public class AppHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute 
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        Exception ex = filterContext.Exception;
        //TODO 
        //LogManager.GetLogger("Exception").Error(ex.Message);
        if (filterContext.Exception is UserException){
            if(!string.isNullOrEmpty(this.View))
            {
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                filterContext.Result = ...;//<===this.View(custom Page)
            }
            else{ 
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                filterContext.Result = ...;//<==='XYZ' page(another custom page)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And In  Web.Config Set:

```
<customErrors mode="On"/>
```

**Edit Begin**

And In FilterConfig I set:

```
 public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new AppHandleErrorAttribute() );
    }
```

**End**

Then I just want the Action of 'Test()' to run AppHandleErrorAttribute for Once.

```
public class XXXController:Controller{
   public ActionResult Test()
    {
        throw new UserException("test0x11", "test", null);
        return View();
    }


    [AppHandleError(View="Index")]//<=======here I want the Test2 to Index View, but it will be call AppHandleError twice this time
    //it always Redirect to 'XYZ' page 
    public string Test2()
    {
        throw new UserException("test0x12", "test", null);
        return "haha";
    }
    public string Index(){...}
}
```

How can I do not call globle HandleError?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Do you have "~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml" file ?

Comment: @Dima Yes,I can redirect to Index Page in AppHandleErrorAttribute .But if I set [AppHandleError(View="XXX")] then the AppHandleError will run  twice. the first time View=xxx and The second time it will be 500 page!

Comment: It seems like an error on View=xxx that caused second 500 error. Have you looked at StackTraces for both cases?

Comment: @Dima I fix the My qustion,and the 500 page is My create Page that is not System Page